# Posting to a Facebook wall using a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

**Overview:**

I got a website that has sentences that people can post to Facebook, but in each sentence there are input boxes, which people can change the default value. Kind of like a digital "Mad Lib". Each line has a button which will post that line to Facebook.

**Help with:**

Having a single function to post the data of the button being pressed to Facebook. I could just name the function differently and add the variables, but it defeats the purpose of a function.

**HTML**

```
<div id="post1">
    <span>I like</span>
        <input name="post1_1" value="Tom" type="text" id="post1_1" />
    <span>I think she is</span><input name="post1_2" value="Nice" type="text" id="post1_2" />

    <a href="javascript:Post(post1)">POST NOW</a>
</div>

<div id="post2">
    <span>My website is</span>
    <input name="post2_1" value="Great" type="text" id="post2_1" />
    <a href="javascript:Post(post2)">POST NOW</a>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function postonwall(post1, post2)
{
    var post1_1 = null;
    var post1_2 = null;
    var post2_2 = null;
    var post2_3 = null;

    var post1_1 = $("#post1_1").val();
    var post1 = "I like" + post1_1 + ". I think she is" + post1_2;

    var post2_1 = $('#post2_1').val();
    var post2 = "My website is" + post2_1;

    FB.api('/me/feed',
           'post',
           {
               message: post1,
               message: post2
           }, function(response) {
               if (!response || response.error) {
                   alert('Oops! User Denied Access');
               }
               else {
                   alert('Success: Content Published');
               }
           });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the FB API, but if you can post only one message per request, then you can create an array of messages and then loop through it to post.

```
var messages = [
     msg1, msg2, msg3
];

for(var i in messages){
    // here comes your code to post to facebook
}
```

This would be called when the user clicks a button. If this is not what you meant, please give us some more info so we can help :D

Comment: Could I pass the specific variable through the function when called? <a href="javascript:Post(post1)">POST NOW</a>? Then It would just take that specific variable (post1) to post?

Comment: Just looking at your code was not very clear...what does the function Post does? From what I understood, your postonwall function does all the work alone, you just need to call it when you want to save the results to Facebook.

I believe there would be a `<a href="javascript:postonwall()">POST NOW</a>` and this link would call your function.

Comment: Ended up doing something else. Thanks